# Find process responsible for memory spikes

Tags: linux, wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on a shared Red Hat 4.4.7-18 Linux box and from time to time I get huge memory and I/O spikes exceding my allowed memory limit making my website unresponsive.

I have Cpanel installed but there is no way I can find out exactly what process is causing this but only seeing those spikes.

I think this is being caused by one of my plugins and would really want to know which of them does that. I have 15+ plugin installed so disabling and monitoring if the issue still exists it's not an option as this apparently happens randomly.

[image: Cpanel]

Comment: You need to intall and do an analyse using xdebug cachegrind need to be implemented https://codex.wordpress.org/Testing_WordPress_Performance

Comment: What if the problem it's not within the wordpress engine and has something to do with another php-based software installed on the same box like piwik for example? Having SSH access is there a server-side solution in monitoring this issue?

Comment: if is just for `supervision` you can install **zabix, nagios ...** the first one is a little bit more full of services. Just look on demands of what you want to monitoring. I guess if your are not on a dedicate server or your host can do it for you depend of the services taken with them.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @headmax as far as I can tell there is no way I can install scrips on my sharing account

Comment: @StephanieSafflower did you call the hosting about this? do an analyse for you.

Comment: @jww I understand that and I am sorry if I've posted in the wrong section. Is there a way I could move this to the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://www.hlbenefits.com) section or should I just open a new thread there?

Comment: @headmax This is the first thing I did but they used an analogy like this: "Think about us like an electrical company, we supply energy for your devices and we can tell you when your maximum allowed energy levels have been reached but cannot tell you what device consumed most of that energy" - And they are one of the leading hosting providers out there. They also advised me to upgrade my plan so they have no interest in debugging my issue but in selling me additional services.

Comment: @StephanieSafflower :( i guess if you don't check yourself this server or change hosting i guess is a good issue on regarding of this situation. i think you have to check your logs /var/logs/ of all services

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)